# Boolean value of numbers and strings in COBOL

Tags: boolean, cobol

Most programming languages recognize any non-zero number and non-blank string as true. I am wondering if COBOL does the same?

Example1: (9 && 2) is recognized (true && true) so returns true
Example2: ("" && "Hello") is recognized (false && true) so returns false

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Cobol **does not** have Boolean's as other languages do, it has 88 levels instead.
88 levels can be applied to other types. They cover boolean and enums in
other languages.

### Basic boolean 88 level

you can do

```
    05 Filler              pix x value 'N'.
       88 end-of-file value 'Y'.
       88 more-date-in-file value 'N'


    perform until   end-of-file
        ...

        read Transaction-File
         at end set end-of-file    to True
   end-perform
```

### basic enum 88 level

```
  03 Transaction-Code                pic s9(4) comp-3.
     88 Purchase-Transaction value    1000, 1001, 1005 thru 1009.
     88 Sales-Transaction    value    2000, 2010, 2020.
     88 Price-Adjustment     value    2050.
     88 Transfer-Transaction value    1050.



  evaluate true
     when Purchase-Transaction
       ...
     when Sales-Transaction    
       ...
```

### Summary

**88 levels** provide basic boolean variables (but no boolean algebra). They also 
allow you to document the possible values a variable can take + there meaning.

**88 levels** are one of the *nicer* features of Cobol especially when **used with files**. It allows you to define **exactly** what values a Field in a File can have. 
In *Java* etc, you could define constants but you **can not link a Constant** to a variables. You can use enum's but that will require extra code and are limited to one value. Of course files are not as important as they once where.

Answer (score 0):

From a Google search:

> Boolean data items COBOL does not directly support logical/boolean
>   variables; however, level-88 is used to define condition names which
>   have the same effect.